# Animated Dashed Border in Android

Tags: android, animation, border

How do you create an animated dashed or dotted border of an arbitrary shape in Android? In XML (preferred) or programmatically.

See picture below for an example.

[image]

Comment: Is it desirable in a mobile device? Besides being about as attractive as the BLINK tag, it's going to eat battery power. If this is about ads, that's not the way to get happy customers.

Comment: It's desirable for my use case. It's for a graphics app, and the dashed animation border is an universal symbol for a mask. Also, I don't think this will eat more battery power than say, a live background.

Comment: OK, I suspected nefarious advertising purposes. That's a reasonable purpose.

Comment: A reasonable suspicion. Every time I return here I think the image is a banner ad. And it's my own question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you seen the PathEffects API demo?
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/PathEffects.html

It produces precisely an animated line and you can just adjust the path to the edge of your view to create a border. For example:

Define a path by your view parameters / arbitrary shape:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addRect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom(), Path.Direction.CW);
```

Then create a dashed PathEffect with:

```
PathEffect pe = new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10, 5, 5, 5}, phase);
```

Then set the associate it with a Paint object and draw:

```
mPaint.setPathEffect(pe);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

EDIT: The animated effect comes from continuously changing the phase and redrawing. In the API demo it calls invalidate() in the onDraw() method (which triggers onDraw()...)

Comment: Thanks antonyt! This is exactly what I was looking for. Pity it can't be defined in xml.

Comment: One issue with this is that it allocates a lot of objects that will trigger garbage collection and might cause your animation to stutter. You can avoid part of the issue by allocating the float[] as a class member somewhere. Not sure how to avoid the DashPathEffect allocation each time the phase changes, although of course you could handle the animation yourself by translating the lines.

Comment: You can create an array of DashPathEffects (of size equal to the highest number in the float array, 10 in this case), and re-use these effects. At least this is what I'm doing, but for the `PathDashPathEffect` effect.

Answer (score 0):

XML... I guess not possible. But you can use a custom view or a SurfaceView and handle the drawing by yourself. Have fun with that :)

Comment: Any pointers to implement it with a custom view or SurfaceView?

Comment: you can draw lines on every canvas and the used Paint object can have different styles. If you change between white line with a black dashed line above and black line with white dashed line above on every frame, you should get the wished effect.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use some form of two 9patch images as a background frame around the image file you want to present, one in each of two layouts. The images would differ in terms of the placement of the dashed elements. Interchange the views rapidly (might need a delay) and you might get the effect you want. Don't really know how effective that would be though in terms of being able to let the user continue using the app and chewing battery...

Comment: Two 9 patch images in an animation drawable. That might work, and is doable via XML. Will give it a try.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. 9 patch images do not repeat patterns, they just stretch a part of the image.

Comment: Sorry, what I was getting at is that you create two images in 9patch format. You will have to create the patterns yourself but in such a way that if you were to rapidly switch between them it would create the illusion that the dashes were moving.

Comment: The switch can be done with an animation drawable. However, I don't understand how the 9patch images can be used to create a resolution independent dotted border (animated or not).

Comment: I don't think 9patchs will be useful in this situation, there is no way to specify them to tile a section like he wants.